# gdiplus members is ambiguous

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, gdi+

I'm trying to run code from this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534077(v=vs.85).aspx  in win32 console application (VS 2012)
and have this errors:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdiplusStartup@12 referenced in function _main   c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdiplusShutdown@4 referenced in function _main   c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipLoadImageFromFileICM@8 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Gdiplus::Image::Image(wchar_t const *,int)" (??0Image@Gdiplus@@QAE@PB_WH@Z)    c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipLoadImageFromFile@8 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Gdiplus::Image::Image(wchar_t const *,int)" (??0Image@Gdiplus@@QAE@PB_WH@Z)   c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipGetImageWidth@8 referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall Gdiplus::Image::GetWidth(void)" (?GetWidth@Image@Gdiplus@@QAEIXZ)    c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipGetImageHeight@8 referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall Gdiplus::Image::GetHeight(void)" (?GetHeight@Image@Gdiplus@@QAEIXZ) c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipFree@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Gdiplus::GdiplusBase::operator delete(void *)" (??3GdiplusBase@Gdiplus@@SAXPAX@Z) c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipDisposeImage@4 referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Gdiplus::Image::~Image(void)" (??1Image@Gdiplus@@UAE@XZ)   c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipCloneImage@8 referenced in function "public: virtual class Gdiplus::Image * __thiscall Gdiplus::Image::Clone(void)" (?Clone@Image@Gdiplus@@UAEPAV12@XZ)  c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipAlloc@4 referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl Gdiplus::GdiplusBase::operator new(unsigned int)" (??2GdiplusBase@Gdiplus@@SAPAXI@Z)   c:\Users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.obj    ConsoleApplication4
Error   11  error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals  c:\users\администратор\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe  ConsoleApplication4
```

in gdiplusinit.h i see that GdiplusStartupInput,GdiplusStartupOutput,DebugEventLevel is ambiquous. Any knows how fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no ambiguity here, you simply forgot to link gdiplus.lib.  Add it to the linker's Input + Additional Dependencies setting.

An easy way is to put the link directive in your source code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib")
```

Comment: Additional information about adding the mentioned gdiplus.lib when you use Visual Studio.
Right-click on your project in the solution explorer.
Select Properties.
Fold open the Linker section.
Select Input.
Add gdiplus.lib to the values at Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Yup, that's what it says in the first paragraph.

Comment: I know, but I spend some time trying to find out where. So my comment was just some extra clarification on top of your answer

Answer (score 1):

All the errors you posted are symbols not resolved by the Linker.
It seems you forgot to add a lib (something like `gdi.lib` or `gdiplus.lib` ) to your VS project.